# Virtualbox 4.3.10 on Win 8.1 no usb for Win 7 VM

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, virtualbox

I have a new Asus laptop(64bit) running windows 8.1, installed virtualbox 4.3.10(latest) and installed a window 7(64 bit) VM with extentions(guest additions...). I have tried every combination from usb filters to removing and reinstalling the drivers on the windows 7 VM. I cannot get any usb device that is being see ok from windows 8 on the windows 7 VM, nothing at all. Can someone shine some light on getting the usb ports to work. What is the trick?

Comment: I assume you [forwarded the usb devices](http://www.arvydas.co.uk/2011/02/forwarding-usb-devices-on-oracle-virtualbox/)?